# On union with NULL, rows are repeating

Tags: mysql

I have a sql query, in which I have joined two columns using Union including null.
Here is my query :

```
select users.id, 
users.name, 
users.email, 
users.image, 
users.created_at, 
users.is_online, 
friends.user_id, 
friends.friend_id, 
friends.accept from users left join friends on users.id=friends.friend_id 
where users.id != 18 and (friends.user_id = 18 or friends.user_id is NULL) 
UNION 
select users.id, 
users.name, 
users.email, 
users.image, 
users.created_at, 
users.is_online, 
friends.user_id, 
friends.friend_id, 
friends.accept from users left join friends on users.id=friends.user_id 
where users.id != 18 and (friends.friend_id = 18 or friends.friend_id is NULL) 
order by id asc
```

Its working fine but its repeating the rows in case 1 column contains the value and other is null, I just want to remove the null value containing row,

```
 id |  created_at |    name     |        email               |      image      | is_online | user_id | friend_id | accept 
 ------------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------
  1 |  2020-03-24 | yashyashwi  | yashyashwi@gmail.com       | 1596540233.jpeg | 0         |      18 |         2 |  0 
  4 |  2020-03-25 | Jesly Benny | benny@gmail.com            | 1596540244.jpeg | 0         |      18 |      4    |  2 
  4 |  2020-03-26 | Jesly Benny | benny@gmail.com            | 1596540334.jpeg | 0         |    NULL |      NULL |  NULL 
  5 |  2020-03-27 | Zasika      | Zasika@gmail.com           | 1596540334.jpeg | 0         |      5  |        18 |  0
```

Please help me out

Comment: If you don't want rows with nulls in the results then use INNER join instead of LEFT join.

Comment: I want the rows with NULL. Here, its only 4 rows. I have many rows in it with NULL.. I just want to remove the rows which have repeated NULL values

Comment: Is it always the case that when you have in the results 2 rows for the same id one of them contains nulls and you want to remove it?

Comment: yes, I want to remove it